# Add CSS class to <form> element using webform and template file

Tags: theming, webforms

I have an existing webform in Drupal 7 which I am trying to theme.
So far I managed to add CSS classes, placeholders, prefix, suffix,.. to form *elements* (fields) but not to the actual `<form>`-tag?

I tried this:

```
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-horizontal';`
```

But that didn't change anything to the output.

edit: I have found that putting `var_dump($form['#attributes']);` displays the array below the form-tag. Does that mean that you cannot alter the root element inside a template file (webform-form-8.tpl.php) and that I should implement the hook in template.php?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your edit is correct. You should add the class in a preprocessor function within template.php.

A similar question and answer can be found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28583/alter-a-select-form-using-preprocess-function).

Answer (score 0):

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my_class';
}
```

in a template.php